# Total by Date in Pivot sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have curret query like this to create pivot table and count the items

```js
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(20),
    Item varchar(10),
    Date varchar(8)
)
INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170611'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Pen', '20170610'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Laptop', '20170611'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170611'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pen', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Laptop', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610')

 DECLARE @Pivot_Columns  AS VARCHAR(MAX),
   @select_Columns VARCHAR(max)

 SELECT @Pivot_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
 SELECT @select_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Sum(' + Quotename(Item) + ') as '+Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

 DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then ''Total''+ '' '' + name 
 when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then ''Total'' 
 else name end Name, location, '
      + @select_Columns + '
 FROM
 (
  SELECT name, location, item
  FROM #SampleData

 ) as PivotData
 PIVOT
 (
  count(item)
  for item  IN ('
      + @Pivot_Columns + ')
 ) AS PivotResult
 group by name,location with rollup 
 '

 EXEC(@SQL)
```

and the result like this

[image]

how to create Total by date below the grand total?

[image]

i've tried to using union and it doesn't work.
how to create total like my image? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using dynamic SQL. Try this static SQL:

```
SELECT case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then 'Total'+ ' ' + name 
when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then 'Total' 
else name end Name, location, Sum([Laptop]) as [Laptop],Sum([Pen]) as [Pen],Sum([Pencil]) as [Pencil]
FROM
(
    SELECT name, location, item
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ([Laptop],[Pen],[Pencil])
) AS PivotResult
group by name,location with rollup 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' Name, location, Sum([Laptop]) as [Laptop],Sum([Pen]) as [Pen],Sum([Pencil]) as [Pencil]
FROM
(
    SELECT [date] as location, item
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ([Laptop],[Pen],[Pencil])
) AS PivotResult
group by location
;
```

Comment: thank you,  i can improve your answer with dynamic sql and it's worked.

Comment: Great. I  always use static sql first.